# Instantiating module inside for loop

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to write Verilog code for converting any digit decimal number to a BCD number.

My logic: when I read decimal number, I'll extract the decimal number digit by digit, and I have written a module to convert the decimal digit (0 to 9) to BCD.
But, I'm getting an error in the line:

```
dec_to_bcd_0_to_9 a(temp2, bcd_num [(3*i)+(i-1):4*(i-1)]);
```

It is showing a syntax error in the Icarus Verilog simulator.
What is wrong in my code?

```
module dec_to_bcd_0_to_9(dec,bcd);
input integer dec;
output reg [3:0] bcd;

always@*
begin

case(dec)
1'd0:bcd=4'b0000;
 
1'd1:bcd=4'b0001;

1'd2:bcd=4'b0010;

1'd3:bcd=4'b0011;
 
1'd4:bcd=4'b0100;
 
1'd5:bcd=4'b0101;
 
1'd6:bcd=4'b0110;
 
1'd7:bcd=4'b0111;
         
1'd8:bcd=4'b1000;
 
default:bcd=4'b1001;
endcase

end

endmodule

module dec_to_bcd_any_number(dec_width,dec_num,bcd_num);
input integer  dec_width,dec_num;
output [4*dec_width-1:0] bcd_num;

reg integer temp1,temp2;

assign temp1=dec_num/10;
assign temp2=dec_num%10;

generate
genvar i;

for(i=1;i<=dec_width;i=i+1)
begin
dec_to_bcd_0_to_9 a(temp2, bcd_num [(3*i)+(i-1):4*(i-1)]);
assign temp2=temp1%10;
assign temp1=temp1/10;
end

endgenerate
endmodule
```

Comment: Beware that the / and % operator are not support by all synthesis tools for values which are not a power of two.

Comment: then what is the solution for this problem if we want to synthesize?

Comment: There is no easy solution, that is why I pointed this out. Ultimately you might have to implement a divider. Multiplication is easy so you can make "% 10" by using the division result, multiply it by 10 and then subtraction from the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems.

- First, you can't use `integer` as the type of an input port. In fact, iverilog seems to treat it as equivalent to `reg`, which means you can't use it in `assign` statements either. You need to replace it with a `wire` with an explicit width.
- Second, the limits of a `for` loop need to be known at compile time, so you can't base it on an input port. `dec_width` must be a module parameter instead.
- Also, there was a minor problem with declaring an explicit width of 1 bit for your `case` values.

Here's a version of your code that compiles cleanly with `iverilog -tnull ...`:

```
module dec_to_bcd_0_to_9 (dec, bcd);
  input [31:0] dec;
  output reg [3:0] bcd;

  always @* begin
    case (dec)
      'd0:     bcd = 4'b0000;
      'd1:     bcd = 4'b0001;
      'd2:     bcd = 4'b0010;
      'd3:     bcd = 4'b0011;
      'd4:     bcd = 4'b0100;
      'd5:     bcd = 4'b0101;
      'd6:     bcd = 4'b0110;
      'd7:     bcd = 4'b0111;
      'd8:     bcd = 4'b1000;
      default: bcd = 4'b1001;
    endcase
  end
endmodule

module dec_to_bcd_any_number (dec_num, bcd_num);
  parameter dec_width = 5;
  input [31:0] dec_num;
  output [4*dec_width-1:0] bcd_num;

  wire [31:0] temp1, temp2;

  assign temp1 = dec_num/10;
  assign temp2 = dec_num%10;

  generate
    genvar i;

    for (i = 1; i <= dec_width; i = i+1) begin
      dec_to_bcd_0_to_9 a (temp2, bcd_num [(3*i)+(i-1):4*(i-1)]);
      assign temp2 = temp1%10;
      assign temp1 = temp1/10;
    end
  endgenerate
endmodule
```

Comment: Thank you. but I am getting "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" for every decimal value that I am giving from test bench. is it beacuse my logic incorrect?

Comment: Yes. What you do next is called "debugging". Look at each of the variables in the order in which they are assigned, and verify that they have the expected values. As soon as you find a discrepancy, stop and figure out why.